# Why do I get this error: "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context."?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, error-handling, three.js

I have a program in which I am working with canvas and I am using the three.min.js library. When I run the program, it doesn't show anything, but when I pressed Ctrl + Shift + J in Google Chrome it showed me this error:

[image]

I am using Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 m for PC.

The funny thing is that yesterday it worked.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Could be because WebGL has crashed. Did you reboot your Chrome, or the machine? Did this exact code work yesterday, or did it work before it was edited, but not since? Are you using ShaderMaterial or RawShaderMaterial?

Comment: @bjorke I restarted the computer and it still doesn't work. Yesterday the exact code worked even with some modifications. I don't even use any shaders in my code.

Comment: now f12 is same than Ctrl+Shift+J :) Also you will understand issues if you use the _unminified_ version `three.js`. As the console logs, the context creation (method `canvas.getContext('webgl', params)` returns `null`. There is a problem with your canvas or with the params (antialias, alpha..).

Comment: Can you post the relevant code like WebGL context creation? Also you may want to link with the unminified version of three.js to see exactly where the error is coming from.

Comment: Meet the same problem on Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m

Comment: use !Detector.webgl to check webgl support

Answer (score 0):

Enabling GPU acceleration on chrome going to chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist might help solve the issue.

Comment: The actual link is chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blocklist (block, not black). It didn't solve the issue for me, but thanks for it.